# Windows command equivalent of egrep

Tags: windows, command

Can I run this in a Windows command prompt like I can run it in UNIX?

```
egrep -wi 'FRIENDS|FOES' *.sql
```

This command is intended to scan each SQL file for the whole keywords "Friends" and "Foes," ignoring case.

Comment: Have you looked at the findstr command? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Windows CLI is missing some features that us Linux refuges take for granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `findstr` command is a fair enough substitute Windows command in place of Linux.

Answer (score 5):

Well you can have [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) on Windows so then you have `bash`, `grep`, etc.

If you need only grep, then there is [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).

If you don't want to install anything and is on Win XP, try `findstr`, although it can't do "orring".

If you are on Win-7, then there is `powershell`, with [`select-string`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/03/23/select-string-and-grep.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The Windows equivalent would be the FIND command:

```
C:\>find /?
Searches for a text string in a file or files.

FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] [/OFF[LINE]] "string" [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /V         Displays all lines NOT containing the specified string.
  /C         Displays only the count of lines containing the string.
  /N         Displays line numbers with the displayed lines.
  /I         Ignores the case of characters when searching for the string.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  "string"   Specifies the text string to find.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

If a path is not specified, FIND searches the text typed at the prompt
or piped from another command.
```

But you can also download most of the unix utilities (incl. grep) from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ (just drop them into your PATH and use them).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your system. Do you have some version of grep installed? Windows has no equvalent of grep out of the box, but you can install Cygwin / GnuWin or [unxutils.sourceforge.net](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sure about the OR condition, but the basic feature should look like

```
type *.sql | find /n "FRIENDS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a equivalent to egrep "string1|string2|string3":

PS: C:> findstr /C:string1 /C:string2 /C:string3

Answer (score 0):

here it is

```
findstr /I /C:FRIENDS /C:FOES *.sql
```

Searches for strings in files.

```
FINDSTR [/B] [/E] [/L] [/R] [/S] [/I] [/X] [/V] [/N] [/M] [/O] [/P] [/F:file]
        [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:dir list] [/A:color attributes] [/OFF[LINE]]
        strings [[drive:][path]filename[ ...]]

  /B         Matches pattern if at the beginning of a line.
  /E         Matches pattern if at the end of a line.
  /L         Uses search strings literally.
  /R         Uses search strings as regular expressions.
  /S         Searches for matching files in the current directory and all
             subdirectories.
  /I         Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive.
  /X         Prints lines that match exactly.
  /V         Prints only lines that do not contain a match.
  /N         Prints the line number before each line that matches.
  /M         Prints only the filename if a file contains a match.
  /O         Prints character offset before each matching line.
  /P         Skip files with non-printable characters.
  /OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with offline attribute set.
  /A:attr    Specifies color attribute with two hex digits. See "color /?"
  /F:file    Reads file list from the specified file(/ stands for console).
  /C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string.
  /G:file    Gets search strings from the specified file(/ stands for console).
  /D:dir     Search a semicolon delimited list of directories
  strings    Text to be searched for.
  [drive:][path]filename
             Specifies a file or files to search.

Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is prefixed
with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches for "hello" or
"there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y' searches for
"hello there" in file x.y.

Regular expression quick reference:
  .        Wildcard: any character
  *        Repeat: zero or more occurrences of previous character or class
  ^        Line position: beginning of line
  $        Line position: end of line
  [class]  Character class: any one character in set
  [^class] Inverse class: any one character not in set
  [x-y]    Range: any characters within the specified range
  \x       Escape: literal use of metacharacter x
  \<xyz    Word position: beginning of word
  xyz\>    Word position: end of word
For full information on FINDSTR regular expressions refer to the online Command
Reference.
```